# Gigabit LTE mobile routers with ethernet

Tags: router, ethernet, 4g

I'm looking for a replacement for my Nighthawk M1 which I just returned. There doesn't seem to LTE-only replacements, the Nighthawk M1 (Cat 16) and M2 (Cat 20) seem to be the only ones with over Cat 9 speeds.

But, looking at 5G mobile routers there seems to be more options, like the HTC 5G Hub.

Are there not any gigabit LTE mobile routers beside the Nighthawks?

Comment: Any reason why it has to be LTE-only?

Comment: @Lawrence ok, i removed that rejuirement.

Answer (score 1):

The Huawei E5788u-96a is a LTE router with CAT16 speeds

https://www.amazon.com.au/Huawei-E5788u-96a-1Gbps-Mobile-Globally/dp/B075KMWV9K

Another option is the Huawei H112-372

https://www.router-switch.com/huawei-5g-cpe-pro.html

Seems that Huawei, Netgear, and HTC are the only companies at the moment that make gigabit LTE routers.

Comment: I adjusted my question a bit to include ethernet but I still consider this an answer as there are wireless bridges.